# I want to display single notification on the phone when multiple user like the same post in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

1. For example User posting a feed . He got  10 likes on his post.He got 10 notifications on his phone.I want to display single notification for this like Facebook.It should say You and 9 other people likes your post.  How to implement this.
2. Instead of  10 notification individually I want to show single notification that's what i want. Is it possible in APNS .
3. Basically I want to group those 10 notification into a single notification because different user like the same post.

Comment: **It should say You and 9 other people likes your post.** , You are asking for one thing, but explaining something else. Also, this question is not fit here. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: First thing is that fb not post a push notification while some one like any post. second thing is that you can update the exising notification entry when some one like it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Facebook, Than i don't think Facebook sent any push notification when some one like your post. that is local notification tab managed.

So the idea or logic behind it that you can manage each like for the same post by updating notification tab cell by post id. for example:

You manage core-data to show notifications like You and other 5 like that post then you need to maintain its notification table by post_id, user_id and many other related filed. so once 9 user liked that post you can get a count of user by post id who liked the post let's say you found 9 user including you then you can show the text in notification tab like You and 8 other people likes your post. decrease 1 - total number of peoples. Each like you need to fire any trigger that check existing like and update the existing entry.

So somethings like that logic you can handle in side app notification flow.